# Как передать значение из одного класса в другой

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Начал учить kivy. Решил попробовать написать небольшое приложение с регистрацией пользователей. Остановился на моменте добавление подробной информации. Не могу понять как передать логин из класса `Registers` (`TextInput: id: field_login`) в класс `About_myself` чтобы дальше привязать доп информацию о пользователе.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.config import ConfigParser
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('bd.sqlite', check_same_thread = False)

with open('style.kv', encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    Builder.load_string(f.read())

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass
     
class Entry(Screen):
    pass

class Registers(Screen):
    def button_clicked(self, login,pswd):
        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            sql = f'''INSERT INTO user (id,username,password)
            VALUES (NULL,'{login}','{pswd}');
            '''
            try :
                cursor.execute(sql)
                self.ids.result_label.text = "Спасибо за регистрацию!"
            except:
                self.ids.result_label.text = "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует!"


class About_myself(Screen):
    def but_click(self,id_user,name,secondname):
        with conn:
            cursor=conn.cursor()
            sql = f'''INSERT INTO user_info (id_user,name,secondname)
            VALUES ({id_user}'{name}','{secondname}');
            ''' 



class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kvargs)
        self.screen_manager = Factory.ManagerScreens()

    def build(self):
        return self.screen_manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

style.kv

```
<ManagerScreens@ScreenManager>:
    
    MenuScreen:
        id: menu
    Entry:
        id: entry
    Registers:
        id: registers
    About_myself
        id: about

<MenuScreen@Screen>:
    name: "menu"
    _app: app
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 255, 255, 255
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 150
        TextInput:
            id: field_login
            multiline: False
            height: dp(40)
            size_hint_y: None
            hint_text: "Введите логин"

        TextInput:
            id: field_pswd
            multiline: False
            height: dp(40)
            size_hint_y: None
            hint_text: "Введите пароль"
        Label:
            id: result_label
        
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Вход"
                height: dp(40)
                size_hint_y: None
            Button:
                text: "Регистрация"
                height: dp(40)
                size_hint_y: None
                on_press: app.screen_manager.current = 'registers'

<Entry>
    name: "entry"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Button:
            text: '< Назад в главное меню'
            on_press: app.screen_manager.current = 'menu'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)

<Registers>
    name: "registers"

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 150
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        TextInput:
            id: field_login
            multiline: False
            height: dp(40)
            size_hint_y: None
            hint_text: "Введите логин"

        TextInput:
            id: field_pswd
            multiline: False
            height: dp(40)
            size_hint_y: None
            hint_text: "Введите пароль"

        Label:
            id: result_label

        Button:
            text:'Зарегистрироваться'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)
            on_press:
                if field_login.text != '' and field_pswd.text!='':root.button_clicked(field_login.text,field_pswd.text);app.screen_manager.current = 'about'
                else: result_label.text = 'Введите логин и пароль'
                field_login.text = ''
                field_pswd.text = ''

        Button:
            text: '< Назад в главное меню'
            on_press: app.screen_manager.current = 'menu'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)


<About_myself>
    name:"about"
    
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 150
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: field_name
            multiline: False
            height: dp(40)
            size_hint_y: None
            hint_text: "Введите имя"

        TextInput:
            id: field_secondname
            multiline: False
            height: dp(40)
            size_hint_y: None
            hint_text: "Введите фамилию"

        Button:
            text:'Сохранить доп.информацию о себе'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного подправил код. Добавил новую функцию для передачи параметра. Пометил комментариями в коде.

```
class Registers(Screen):
    def pars(self, text): #новая функция
        sm.get_screen('about').ids.name.text = text
    
    def button_clicked(self, login,pswd):
        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            sql = f'''INSERT INTO user (id,username,password)
            VALUES (NULL,'{login}','{pswd}');
            '''
            try :
                cursor.execute(sql)
                self.ids.result_label.text = "Спасибо за регистрацию!"
            except:
                self.ids.result_label.text = "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует!"

class About_myself(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(Entry(name='entry'))
sm.add_widget(Registers(name='registers'))
sm.add_widget(About_myself(name='about'))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

и в kv файле добавить

```
<Registers>
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 150
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        TextInput:
            id: field_login
            multiline: False
            height: dp(40)
            size_hint_y: None
            hint_text: "Введите логин"

        TextInput:
            id: field_pswd
            multiline: False
            height: dp(40)
            size_hint_y: None
            hint_text: "Введите пароль"

        Label:
            id: result_label

        Button:
            text:'Зарегистрироваться'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)
            on_press:
                root.pars(field_login.text) #вызов функции для передачи текста
                if field_login.text != '' and field_pswd.text!='':root.button_clicked(field_login.text,field_pswd.text);app.screen_manager.current = 'about'
                else: result_label.text = 'Введите логин и пароль'
                field_login.text = ''
                field_pswd.text = ''

        Button:
            text: '< Назад в главное меню'
            on_press: app.screen_manager.current = 'menu'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(40)
    
BoxLayout: 
    padding: 150
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label: #новое поле в которое передаем текст
        id: name
        color: 255,0,0,1
    TextInput:
        id: field_name
        multiline: False
        height: dp(40)
        size_hint_y: None
        hint_text: "Введите имя"

    TextInput:
        id: field_secondname
        multiline: False
        height: dp(40)
        size_hint_y: None
        hint_text: "Введите фамилию"

    Button:
        text:'Сохранить доп.информацию о себе'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(40)
```

Answer (score -1):

Получить напрямую объект другого класса можно так:
name = EntryMenu().login

Comment: Это не работает